# Is it possible to consult site statistics somewhere to see its evolution with time?

Tags: feature-request, statistics

I was wondering if I can find somewhere the temporal evolution of statistics on site usage (number of visits, answered question and the rest). I have been away for some time and the site seems quieter than it used to be. I was wondering if this is real or it was just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently launched the ["access to site analytics" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260849/proposed-micro-privilege-site-analytics), which lets you do just that.

On beta sites, this privilege is accessible to users with >= 5K reputation on the site (you can [track your progress here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)) (it's raised to 25K afterwards).

There are quite a few users with 5K rep on Chess Stack Exchange. One of them might want to share some of this data with you!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this meta post and comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38266/300411), the numbers on [quantcast.com](https://www.quantcast.com/chess.stackexchange.com?country=US#trafficCard) are accurate:

[image: Chess.SE traffic over last year]

So trending upwards, now solidly above 2k uniques per day.